# Is it possible to mark allure sub step as fail when using pytest-assume

Tags: allure

I have a scenario where my test case in pytest has multiple asserts and i am using pytest-assume plugin to work through all the sub steps so that they execute even if one of them fails.
This works perfectly in pytest and marks the test as failed if any one of the assumes fails.

But when i generate allure reports the test is marked as failed but the sub steps are all shown in green, is there any way to change this in allure

[image: Allure Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

One of not-so-well-mannered, but working approach I used for soft-asserts: inside pytest_runtest_makereport hook get current test instance, go recursively through steps, check statusDetails property of each and fail the needed ones with desired logic of yours.

```py
from allure_commons._core import plugin_manager
from allure_pytest.listener import AllureListener

plugin = next(p for p in plugin_manager.get_plugins() if isinstance(p, AllureListener))
test = plugin.allure_logger.get_test(None)
recursive_search_fail(test.steps)
```

This looks messy, but as far as I've explored, soft assertion and pytest allure are not the best match (especially with many-level nested steps). Also, some other properties of test item might be of help.